# Change default stereotype: Upon adding a Column to a DB-Table, I would like the col stereotype to be my custom stereotpye

Tags: enterprise-architect, stereotype

For our project, wo would like to document certain information with the model in Enterprise Architect, in order to not have multiple sites where stuff get's documented.

A consequence is, that the default model of EAUML::table and EAUML::column is insufficient.

Therefore I started to extend the classes to add our custom properties as shown below.

[image]

Now (after exporting and importing a MDG Profile) I am able to change our defined tables to our new stereotype.

Question here is: Is there a way to change the **default** column stereotype to "CUSTOM Col" for the "CUSTOM Table" instances? I don't seem to find a way. I imagine with a script in the right place or a "substitution" of the right kind. But I am an EA-Newby and have no clue how to solve this.

Thanks for any pointers.
Best

Comment: I don't think there is a _standard_ way to do that. I would think you need to write an add-in to react on the OnPostNew... event.

Comment: On a second thought: template packages. I almost never used them, but they might give you what you want. Just a guess...

Comment: Thansk for yor feedback - i'll give it a look

Comment: No, template packages will not work either. Also some of the standard functionality in EA might not work anymore on extended table and column steretoypes.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I even noticed, that the Attributes in General change for the columns, when I use CUSTOM table instead of EAUML::table. Meaning that EA is programmed to display Attributes like 'Length', 'PK (checkbox)', 'Not Null (checkbox)' for the EAUML::column when the table is EAUML::table, but as soon the stereotype is 'CUSTOM table' the General Attributes mentioned before disappear altough the column stereotype is still set to EAUML::column. 

Do you have an idea where this is coming from? Am I extending the wrong way (Generalize?).

Comment: I'm guessing EA is has pretty much hardcoded the table/column handling based on the stereotype names. I'm afraid there's not much you can do. You could maybe try to **Redefine** the stereotype with your own version of myProfile::table and myProfile::column. That might work, in case EA is only reacting to the stereotype name, and not the fully qualified stereotype.