# Adapt default shape script

Tags: shapes, enterprise-architect

We are extending a types `EAUML::table` to `myProfile::table` and `EAUML::column` to `custom::column`. The new stereotypes have custom tagged values (e.g. Upstream tables, Column status).

We would like to tweak lightly the default shape of `EAUML::table` in order to add the custom tagged values of `myProfile::table` and `myProfile::column`. Therefore I am looking if I can export the default shape-script and adapt rather to rewrite the whole shape-script. Does anybody know how I could achieve this?

Thanks for any help

This question is related to a previous [post I made here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73104397/change-default-stereotype-upon-adding-a-column-to-a-db-table-i-would-like-the)

Answer (score 1):

**No, I'm afraid that is not possible.**

The table shapescript is hardcoded in EA and is not available in any MDG file (unlike say the BPMN shapescripts).

Adding decorations will probably work, but anything else is not going to work.

A decoration can be added by only specifying the decoration in your shapescript

```
decoration key
{
    orientation="sw";
    //big circle
    Arc(10, 35, 65, 90, 42,35,61,50);
    //key part
    moveto(61,50);
    lineto(72,50);
    lineto(72,40);
    lineto(81,40);
    lineto(81,30);
    lineto(90,30);
    lineto(90,10);
    lineto(68,10);
    lineto(41,35);
    //small hole
    Ellipse(25,62,37,75);
}
```

The decoration will then be added to the parent's shape:

[image]

Writing a complete shapescript from scratch, reproducing the standard EA table is going to be very hard, or even impossible, as EA doesn't provide enough tools int the shapescript language to recreate something like the attributes compartment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is disheartening.. but thats how it is then.

Comment: a short follow-up question. What is EA Shapescript lacking for recreating a attribute compartment? It's not poissble to list them or certain information is not available (like public,private, etc..)

Comment: I don't remember exactly. Al I know is that I tried it and came to the conclusion that it couldn't be done properly.